# Real-time interactive simulation

Tags: physics, simulation, interactive

I would like to know how to use mathematica to make a real-time physics simulation that can be interacted with using a cursor.

As an example, consider a classical magnetic dipole in a background field, governed by the equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mathrm{d}t} = \gamma (\mu \times H)$$

We'll suppose that the $H$-field has a constant part along the $z$-axis and an oscillating part in the $x, \, y$ plane. We can solve this system numerically and plot the result.

```
magnetInField = Block[{magnet, field},
    magnet = Table[\[Mu][i][t], {i, 1, 3}];
    field = Table[H[i][t], {i, 1, 3}];
    Thread[D[magnet, t] == \[Gamma] (magnet\[Cross]field)]
  ]

oscillatingField = Block[
    {H, \[Gamma] = 1, magnet, initialCondition, solution, tMax = 100},
    magnet = Table[\[Mu][i][t], {i, 1, 3}];
    initialCondition = 
   Thread[Table[\[Mu][i][0], {i, 1, 3}] == {1, 0, 1}];
    H[1][t_] := A Cos[\[Omega] t]; H[2][t_] := A Sin[\[Omega] t]; 
  H[3][t_] := 1;
    solution = ParametricNDSolveValue[Join[magnetInField,
            initialCondition] // Evaluate,
                magnet,
                {t, 0, tMax}, {\[Omega], A}];
    <|"Solution" -> solution, "MaxTime" -> tMax|>
  ]

ParametricPlot3D[
    oscillatingField["Solution"][2, 1/2],
    {t, 0, oscillatingField["MaxTime"]}
    ]
```

I would like to do something more advanced. I want to be able to grab the dipole with a cursor, orient it, then release it and allow it to precess freely under the field in real time. How do we do this in mathematica?

Comment: See the Locator control of `Manipulate` in the help. They also have some similar examples with ODEs etc.

Comment: @HansOlo `Locator` in `Manipulate` does not support 3D.

Comment: @HansOlo Thanks I will look into that; it might still be useful since there are only two independent variables in the orientation of the dipole moment.

Comment: @cvgmt Hmm, good point, my bad. Still it might be useful for the OP as a starting point

Comment: What is the `dipole`? And why and how  it effect the animation?

Comment: If you need some kind of locator in 3D, there is [`ResourceFunction["Locator3D"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Locator3D/)